# Filter form's main datasource through the linked datasource

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a custom form which has two datasouces. Lets say to make it easer that  my form has the Salestable and SalesLines datasources.

for example I could say that I have a filter which is bounded with the ItemGroup edt .

I want to filter the SalesTable Datasource through this filter in order to 'show' in a grid which is connected with the SalesOrders datasouce :

*''all SalesOrders which 'have' saleslines with  saleslines.ItemGroup == somethingfromFilter*''.

Whatever I tried is faild. Can someone help me?

FYI: the datasources properties I asume that  are proper linked: 
SalesLine.JoinSource = SalesTable
All of my tries was in modified method of the filter.

Comment: Assuming you meant "`modified` method" in your last sentence, could you post the code of that method from your most promising attempt? Please [edit] your question to add the code, do not answer with a comment.

Comment: Can you tell us what link type did you use?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried that has failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume you have an `ItemGroupId` field in the `SalesLine` table.
This is not standard.
Also I will assume you have a filter field in the form called `ItemGroupIdCtrl`.

Add a helper datasource `SalesLineEx`:

- Name: SalesLineEx
- Table: SalesLine
- Allow...: No
- JoinSource: SalesTable
- LinkType: ExistJoin

In the `SalesTable` datasource `executeQuery` modthod:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(salesLineEx_ds.queryBuildDataSource(), fieldNum(SalesLine,ItemGroupId)).value(ItemGroupIdCtrl.text());
    salesLineEx_ds.queryBuildDataSource().enabled(ItemGroupIdCtrl.text() != '');
    super();
}
```

This will check the existence of sales lines with a matching field if the filter field has a value. If no value is entered the filtering datasource is disabled.

Most likely you will want to research after change of filter value:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    salesTable_ds.executeQuery();
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misreading your question, but if you are asking how to filter with ranges, it's a pretty basic task.

Look at `\Forms\PurchTable\Data Sources\PurchLine\Methods\init` to see how they exclude lines that are "Deleted".

If you want to join `SalesLines` to `InventTable` in order to get the item group, you can look at how you can modify the form's query in another example here:

`\Forms\PurchTable\Data Sources\PurchTable\Methods\linkActive`

Answer (score 0):

*Disclimer*: I do not have a AX2012 now. I have posted screenshots from AX2009. Functional is the same

*Prerequisite*: you should have a cross-references to use this functional.

Repro steps:

1. open a form
2. click toolbar button `Advanced Filter/Sort` or `Ctrl+F3`
3. mouse right-click on `Sales order` table in the `Structure` tree.
4. choose and click on `1:n` and than `Order Lines` to add additional table in a filter (you should have a cross-reference)
5. mouse right-click on `Order line` table in the `Structure` tree.
6. choose and click on `n:1` and `Items (Item number)` to add additional table in a filter (you should have a cross-reference)
7. click on `Add` button and choose talble `Items` and field `Item groups` in a Range grid. Specify a `criteria` = `somethingfromFilter`

See screenshots below.

*Note*: Axapta uses additional tables in query only. You need to change a form business logic in AOT to display additional tables/fields on the form.

[image: Add tables with Advanced filter]

[image: Add criteria with added tables]

Answer (score 0):

Filter in a code:

> I have a custom form which has two datasouces.
>
> form has the Salestable and SalesLines datasources.
>
> I want to filter
>
> 'all SalesOrders which 'have' saleslines with saleslines.ItemGroup == somethingfromFilter''

*Prerequisite*: a custom form use two **joined** datasources. `Join type` is one of: Delayed, InnerJoin.

## Solution

It need to modify a method Init in SalesLine datasource.

```
this.query().datasource(tablenum(salesLine)).addDatasource(...)
...
```

See examples in any form with init-method and addDatasource text )

[image: Init-Methods with AddDatasource text]